# Test for Button click to call a mocked function fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Attempting to teach myself testing for React with react-testing library and jest as this is what my work uses.  For the life of me I can not figure out why the mock function testClick is not being called.  I have researched articles and watched videos however most seem outdated as it appears the testing world changes how code should be written super fast.  Anyone have thoughts?  Here's the code :

Products.js component :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { fetchProducts } from '../service';

const Products = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetchProducts();
  };

  const hasBeenClicked = () => {
    console.log('clicked!');
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={product}
          onChange={(e) => setProduct(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <input
        type="submit"
        onClick={hasBeenClicked}
        data-testid="button"
        label="Search"
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

Products.test.js :

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import Products from './Products';


test('Button click triggers click event', () => {
  const testClick = jest.fn();
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Products click={testClick} />);
  const button = getByTestId('button');
  fireEvent.click(button);

  expect(testClick).toBeCalled();
});
```

Results in :

```
 PASS  src/App.test.js
 FAIL  src/components/Products.test.js
  ● Console

    console.log
      clicked!

      at apply (src/components/Products.js:13:13)

  ● Button clicks triggers click event

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      11 |   fireEvent.click(button);
      12 |
    > 13 |   expect(testClick).toBeCalled();
         |                     ^
      14 | });
      15 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Products.test.js:13:21)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.18 s, estimated 4 s
```

Comment: `Products` doesn't receive a `click` prop.

Comment: @ivanatias  Could you provide an example please?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to test upon a user clicking this submit button with certain information? Should a particular product be fetched? Should a particular product be displayed on the screen?

Comment: Just trying to test that clicking the button with ID ```data-testid="button"``` invokes the ```hasBeenClicked``` function.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, you should be focusing your tests on a different perspective. You are sort of trying to test component internals/implementation which you shouldn't, especially when using RTL. What's the end result from a user's POV after clicking this button? What should happen? This is what you should be testing.

Comment: But to answer your question, you are passing your mocked function to `Products` via a `click` prop which it doesn't receive in the first place. This mocked click function is not wired in any way to the button you're clicking on your test. In fact, check the test's logs, `hasBeenClicked` function was called.

Comment: Ok.  Yep, so the code in this question is a functional representation of code I'm working on for employer so it is not the exact code.  It is more of a working example.   I have a tool that tells me this line should be covered and that more specifically that the function triggered by the onClick should be covered.  The original question is how do I make sure the mocked function is called in the test?  I will continue to learn more RTL & Jest testing & take your advice in changing my perspective but for now I just need to figure out how to make this test pass.

Comment: Thanks.  How would I wire this up? Pass the prop from App.js?  Have the ```handleClick``` function live in ```App.js``` and not in ```Product.js```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing your mocked function to `Products` via a `click` prop which the component doesn't receive/expect in the first place. This mocked click function is not wired in any way to the button you're clicking on your test.

To pass this test:

**Products.js:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { fetchProducts } from '../service';

const Products = ({ click }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    fetchProducts()
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={product}
          onChange={(e) => setProduct(e.target.value)}
        />
      </label>
      <input
        type="submit"
        onClick={click}
        data-testid="button"
        label="Search"
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export default Products;
```

**Products.test.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Products from "./Products";

test("Button click triggers click event", () => {
  const testClick = jest.fn();
  render(<Products click={testClick} />);
  const button = screen.getByTestId("button");
  fireEvent.click(button);
  expect(testClick).toBeCalled();
});
```

Comment: This is the solution! My confusion is when I pass the destructured ```click``` prop to ```Products.js``` I can name the prop anything I want and really don't understand why and it still works.  I think I was getting hung up on ```onClick``` as a keyword.  ```Products.js``` is rendered by ```App.js``` and I thought I would need to create something like ```<Products onClick={hasBeenClicked} />;``` to pass the prop to ```Products.js``` however it works without passing the prop from ```App.js``` maybe this has to do with naming a default prop as ```{ click }``` as declared in ```Products.js```

Comment: And now it is time to take a course on RTL & Jest :-)

Comment: For this particular test's sake it doesn't matter if you pass the prop in `App.js` or not, since you are testing the component in isolation. You are rendering the component alone on your test and passing the prop that it needs. Your test will keep passing regardless on if you pass the prop to it in `App.js` or not.